# jQuery catch next div(class)

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a problem. I want to catch div with class `tooltip_content` per click `<i class="tooltip"></i>` in code:

```
<label><span>Data</span><i class="tooltip"></i></label>
    <div class="tooltip_conteiner">
         <div class="tooltip_content">
              <h3>asddd</h3>
          </div>
     </div>
```

With this jQuery code:

```
$(".tooltip").click(function(e) {
        $(this).next("div .tooltip_content").toggle();
});
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, try:

```
$(".tooltip").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('label').next("div").find('.tooltip_content').toggle();
});
```

You need [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the parent `label` and then to its sibling and then do a find.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmErc/)**

if each of your `label` and `tooltip_conteiner` both are enclosed in a container then you could just do:

```
$(this).closest('container').find('.tooltip_content').toggle();
```